# Two Versions of Magento On One Server

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, multistore, multidomain

I am having trouble with a task of setting up two Magento installations on the the same server, the goal is to have two stores both running seperate versions of Magento.

I am in `Apache 2.4` and the first Magento instance I installed was the newer version. Then I created a virtual host file and edited my DNS records so as to host the second version of Magento on a subdomain, `old.example.com`

My problem is that whenever I go to `old.example.com` it redirects me to `example.com` and the newer Magento installation, meaning that I can't install the second version or even access it properly.

I believe the problem may have something to do with this:

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

My understanding of the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable leads me to believe that the first Magento installation attached a property to the server environment that means it will always run instead of the second version. Is this correct? How can I stop it from doing that? Or how do I alter this code for the second version so that it can run too? Or am I totally offbase here?

Comment: domain name in core_config_data?

Comment: @MagenX The subdomain isn't configured yet, so it doesn't have a `core_config_data`. I never assigned it a database.

Comment: @MagenX I should also note the domain name for `core_config_data` in the already configured Magento is set correctly, ie doesn't include the subdomain.